# Npgsql EF 6: Timestamp fails when using ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

After update to 6.0.3 I'm getting error in ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync.
Well I know it's a breking change, but I review all my tables in database and all columns are "timestamp without time zone". And doing updates or inserts through the model/DbSet are ok.

With that in mind, take a look at this piece of code:

```
        await Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($@"update nfservico set 
                chavenfse = {chave},
                lotenfse = {cLote},
                lotenfse_dh = {dhRecbto},
                lotenfse_sit = {sit},
                lotenfse_mot = {mot}
                where id = {id}");
```

dhRecbto it's a DateTime parameter with no "kind" specified. Running that give the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot write DateTime with Kind=Unspecified to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp with time zone', only UTC is supported. Note that it's not possible to mix DateTimes with different Kinds in an array/range. See the Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior AppContext switch to enable legacy behavior.
   at Npgsql.Internal.TypeHandlers.DateTimeHandlers.TimestampTzHandler.ValidateAndGetLength(DateTime value, NpgsqlParameter parameter)
   at Npgsql.Internal.TypeHandlers.DateTimeHandlers.TimestampTzHandler.ValidateObjectAndGetLength(Object value, NpgsqlLengthCache& lengthCache, NpgsqlParameter parameter)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter.ValidateAndGetLength()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlParameterCollection.ValidateAndBind(ConnectorTypeMapper typeMapper)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken can...
```

I can't understand the "timestamp with time zone" part, like I said before, the field's without time zone.

I had to do an ugly work around:

```
            var sql = new StringBuilder();
            sql.AppendLine("update nfservico set ");
            sql.AppendLine($"    chavenfse = '{chave}',");
            sql.AppendLine($"    lotenfse = '{cLote}',");
            sql.AppendLine($"    lotenfse_dh = '{dhRecbto:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}',");
            sql.AppendLine($"    lotenfse_sit = {sit},");
            sql.AppendLine($"    lotenfse_mot = '{mot}'");
            sql.AppendLine($"    where id = {id}");
            await Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql.ToString());
```

Anyone with the same issue? And no, I don't want to use "EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior" switch, want to do it right (at least like found at release notes from Npgsql 6).

Comment: You need to convert your `DateTime` into either `DateTimeOffset` or specify kind for it: `dhRecbto = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dhRecbto,DateTimeKind.Utc)`

Comment: Why? "without time zone" field should be DateTime (unspecified/local) like said at https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html  and not an UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation in EF Core's raw SQL support. The EF type mapping - which manages the PG type of the parameter sent (timestamp vs. timestamptz) - is determined only by the CLR type of the parameter (DateTime), without looking at its contents (i.e. the Kind). And the default EF mapping for DateTime is timestamptz, not timestamp; hence the error. Note that this has nothing to do with your actual database column type: it's purely a client-side question.

Fortunately, EF's raw SQL APIs allow passing in a DbParameter directly, allowing you to specify exactly which PostgreSQL type you want:

```cs
var p = new NpgsqlParameter { Value = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0), NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp };
_ = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"SELECT {p}");
```

This is the safe, correct way to pass a parameter where the CLR type (DateTime) has a default PG type (timestamptz) which isn't what you want (you want timestamp). Your workaround above is likely to be wrong in some way, and may introduce an unwanted timezone conversion.

Comment: Right.. I hadn't thought that way. Have fixed it like your suggestion. 
Either way, I think it's wrong.. In the docs the timestamp is the default type and not timestamptz, so the default for DateTime should be timestamp and only if Kind=UTC (the exception) then timestamptz. But thanks, now it's working. Doc Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: Can you point to where exactly you see that "timestamp is the default type and not timestamptz"?

Comment: Sure, this note: "Note: The SQL standard requires that writing just timestamp be equivalent to timestamp without time zone, and PostgreSQL honors that behavior. (Releases prior to 7.3 treated it as timestamp with time zone.) timestamptz is accepted as an abbreviation for timestamp with time zone; this is a PostgreSQL extension."

Comment: So, by the SQL standard the default it's timestamp, which is equals to "without time zone" and then DateTime (unspecified by default) in dotnet. At least it's what I'm understanding.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the sentence you quoted. All it says, is that the `timestamp` type name in PostgreSQL is equivalent to `timestamp without time zone`, not `timestamp with time zone`. That doesn't say anything about how drivers should map the language timestamp representation (DateTime in our case) to PostgreSQL types. The SQL standard does not specify such things.

Comment: I agree, SQL Standard says about database and not programming language, but seems more natural when the defaults are equals. I mean, quickly thinking, I wrote a table with one column timestamp, when I'll use it at code, I'll expect a simple DateTime because these are defaults in both SQL and C#.

Comment: I realy understanding the change, but I my case it's more common to have many DateTime with kind unspecified (by default) and tables with timestamp (again, by default). Now I'll have to write more pieces of code to do the correctly the behavior or just enable the EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior switch. Btw, I think many people will do the last one. Appreciate your point, but that is my opinion.

Comment: My experience is that a *lot* more people use UTC timestamps, which should go into timestamptz rather than timestamp. The SQL standard naming is unfortunate (and don't even get me started about the dumpster fire that is .NET DateTime), but those things shouldn't hold us back. I understand you would have preferred a different default, but there's no single option here that satisfies everyone.

Comment: Sure, I get that some people will just enable EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior, and that's OK. FWIW I've already helped out a lot of users who now properly use timestamptz and DateTime with Kind=UTC for their UTC timestamps - the new change pushed them to do things more correctly.

Comment: I've to agree with you, timestamptz should be the standard. I'm dealing with a bunch local and legacy apps that DB are with timestamp. That's my frustration, I don't need to put this on Npgsql. However, like you say, I should be doing DB migration to corretly timestamptz, but that implicate in change the legacy apps, wich it's very painful. :-(